# SSIS Script component Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to execute SSIS child packages from parent package using multi threading. but when i execute the parent code i get below mentioned error on the **EXECUTE FUNCTION CALL ( TelemetryTrips.Execute(false, null, ChildPackageParams); )**. My code is below, i tried to move the PackageInfo object outside of the Parallel.ForEach function but still in vain. Please suggest.

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'**

Find the code below

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\MS2014;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;";
            //Conncetionstring to the Server of the SSISDB
            SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(SqlCon);

            //Childpackage
            PackageInfo childpckg = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["IGI"].Projects["DEMO"].Packages["TelemetryTrips.dtsx"];

            //Environment
            EnvironmentReference EnvironmentReference = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["IGI"].Projects["DEMO"].References["DEMO", "."];

            string[] Token = new string[2] { "abd6ed6de53d41339641b69664cccc", "abd6ed6de53d41339641bvdssssc046" };
            string ExecutionInstanceGUID = "{7E78DFAB-A01A-4AE2-9A3C-Bxxxxxxxx}";


            Parallel.ForEach(Token[0], new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, TokenRow =>
            {
                string ItemType = "Telemetry Trips";
                PackageInfo TelemetryTrips = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["IGI"].Projects["DEMO"].Packages["TelemetryTrips.dtsx"];
                if (ItemType.Trim() == "Telemetry Trips")
                {
                    //PackageInfo childpckg = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["IGI"].Projects["DEMO"].Packages["TelemetryTrips.dtsx"];

                    Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> ChildPackageParams = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();

                    ChildPackageParams.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
                    {
                        ParameterName = "TokenParam",
                        ParameterValue = Token,
                        ObjectType = 30
                    }
                    );

                    ChildPackageParams.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
                    {
                        ParameterName = "ParentExecutionInstanceGUIDParam",
                        ParameterValue = ExecutionInstanceGUID,
                        ObjectType = 30
                    }
                    );

               **//GETTING THE ERROR HERE**
                    long executionIdentifier = TelemetryTrips.Execute(false, null, ChildPackageParams);

                    //Get execution status
                    //ExecutionOperation executionOperation = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];
                }
            });
```